# Controll merging segments in Lucene

Tags: lucene, merge, segment

I want to have a control in Lucene on the segment merging. To be more precise I have a per segment cache and each time there is a merge I want to have a "callback" and check which segment is going to be merged.

I had a look to the IndexWriter code and looks like its an internal operation of the index writer. I also dont want to hack the IndexWriter. I see an interface called MergeScheduler. Is the best idea to implement this class?

Do you have any idea how to do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could subclass the [`MergePolicy`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/MergePolicy.html) you are using (the default one is `TieredMergePolicy`) and intercept the segments to be merged by overriding the `findMerges` method like this?

```
MergePolicy.MergeSpecification mergeSpecification = super.findMerges(segmentInfos);

// use information from mergeSpecifiation

return mergeSpecification;
```

Comment: The problem is that you need to get the **OneMerge** objects, that are object that have protected fields (and I dont want to hack lucene).

Comment: `segments` field of `MergePolicy.OneMerge` is public -- isn't it the only field that you need?

Comment: `MergePolicy.OneMerge` is public but its field not. So how can I find which segments are merged? There is only one workaround that is a dirty solution and its `MergeSpecification.segString`.

Comment: What version are you using? This API was subject to many changes, but both in [3.6](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/lucene_solr_3_6/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/index/MergePolicy.java#L76) and in [4.0](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/branch_4x/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/index/MergePolicy.java#L76) `segments` field is public.

Comment: You are right, I am using Lucene 3.0.3. I will try to switch. Thank you!